# SyntaxError: Unexpected token / while compiling EJS

Tags: html

I've tried many things but I am still getting this error.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in <path> while compiling ejs
```

I've looked at multiple issues like this one but with no success

This is the part with the error:

```
<% include ./partials/messages %>
```

This is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>404 Page not found</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/fontawesome-all.min.css">
    </head>
    <body id="page-top">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column" id="content-wrapper">
                <div id="content" style="background-color: #000000 !important;height: 100vh;">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand bg-white shadow-lg mb-4 topbar static-top" style="background-color: rgb(247,23,53) !important;">
                        <div class="container-fluid"><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/Logo.png" style="width: 140px;margin: 0 auto;"></div>
                    </nav>
                    <% include ./partials/messages %>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="text-center border rounded shadow-lg mt-5" style="background-color: #ffffff;padding: 25px;max-width: 450px;margin: 0 auto;">
                            <form method="post" action="auth/login">
                                <h1 style="color: rgb(0,0,0);"><strong>Login</strong></h1>
                                <div class="form-group"><label for="password" style="color: rgb(0,0,0);"><strong>ID</strong></label><input class="form-control" type="text" name="id" placeholder="Voer hier het id in." autofocus="" required="" minlength="6" maxlength="6" pattern="\d{6}"></div>
                                <div class="form-group"><label for="password" style="color: rgb(0,0,0);"><strong>Password</strong></label><input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" maxlength="8" required=""><div><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><strong>Login</strong></button>
                            </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="border rounded d-inline scroll-to-top" href="#page-top">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></a></div>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/chart.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/bs-init.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/theme.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this syntax:

```
<%- include('partials/messages'); %>
```